# Variable nested inside another variable not displayed properly in popup in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, point, popup

I would like to set my popup content. Some of the information will be condition-based. I tried the following options:

```js
 onEachFeature: function (pointFeature, layer) {
   var stream = function(liveStr){
     if (pointFeature.properties.Stream === 1) {
       innerHTML = "<p class='webcam_refresh'> Live Stream </p>"
     } else {
      "<p class='webcam_refresh'> Image refresh </p>"
     }
     return liveStr
    };
  var popupContent = L.popup({
  className: 'map-popup',
  }).setContent(
  "<p><h2 class='webcam_location'>" + pointFeature.properties.Location + "</h2></p>" +
  "<h4 class='webcam_provider'>" + pointFeature.properties.Provider + "</h4>" +
  "<iframe src=" + pointFeature.properties.Link + "'&output=embed'height='200' width='300' 
  title='camera thumbnail'></iframe>" + 
 "<b class='popup_category'>Rotation:</b>" + pointFeature.properties.Rotation + stream()
 );
 layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
 }
 }).addTo(map);
```

But as a result, I get only `undefined` value.

Second time I tried something like this:

```js
  onEachFeature: function (pointFeature, layer) {
  var stream = pointFeature.properties.Stream;
    if (pointFeature.properties.Stream === 1) {
      innerHTML = "<p class='webcam_refresh'> Live Stream </p>"
    } else {
      "<p class='webcam_refresh'> Image refresh </p>"
    }
   var popupContent = L.popup({
   className: 'map-popup',
   }).setContent(
   "<p><h2 class='webcam_location'>" + pointFeature.properties.Location + "</h2></p>" +
   "<h4 class='webcam_provider'>" + pointFeature.properties.Provider + "</h4>" +
   "<iframe src=" + pointFeature.properties.Link + "'&output=embed'height='200' width='300' 
   title='camera thumbnail'></iframe>" + 
   "<b class='popup_category'>Rotation:</b>" + pointFeature.properties.Rotation + stream
   );
   layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
   }
   }).addTo(map);
```

Neither first nor second example brought the desired effect.

[image]

How can I define function or variable inside the variable describing the popup in Leaflet?

Comment: What exactly is the result you desire? for example: `... overnight 1`? Could you give an example?

Comment: No, it must be Overnight and if its 1 then "Live Stream" if its 0 then "Camera refresh".

Comment: Do you mean that if it's 1 then `ROTATION: Except overnight Live Stream`, if it's 0 then `ROTATION: Except overnight Camera refresh`? What if it's `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, I did mean exactly this stuff. Undefined means, that the code couldn't read my function properly.

Answer (score 6):

You missed `innerHTML` in `else`, and you should change `+ stream` to `+ innerHTML` in `setContent`. Use this:

```js
onEachFeature: function (pointFeature, layer) {
    var stream = pointFeature.properties.Stream;
    var innerHTML;
    if (stream == 1) {innerHTML = "<p class='webcam_refresh'> Live Stream </p>";}
    else { innerHTML = "<p class='webcam_refresh'> Image refresh </p>"; }


    var popupContent = L.popup({
      className: 'map-popup',
    }).setContent(
      "<p><h2 class='webcam_location'>" + pointFeature.properties.Location + "</h2></p>" +
      "<h4 class='webcam_provider'>" + pointFeature.properties.Provider + "</h4>" +
      "<iframe src=" + pointFeature.properties.Link + "'& output=embed'height='200' width='300' title = 'camera thumbnail' ></iframe > " +
      "<b class='popup_category'>Rotation: </b>" + pointFeature.properties.Rotation + innerHTML
    );
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

[image]